# SpringWebFlux method on request payload no being invoked

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have a web service with a couple of endpoints, one of them is a PUT endpoint that receives an XML and adds some information to a Redis server.

My endpoint is mapped in a configuration class:

```java
@Configuration 
public class RouterConfig {
    @Autowired
    private YAMLConfig yamlConfig;

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoutes(final ServiceHandler serviceHandler) {
        return RouterFunctions.route()
            .GET(yamlConfig.getEnvPrefix() + STATUS_ENDPOINT, serviceHandler::getStatus)
            .GET(yamlConfig.getEnvPrefix() + STOCK_CAP_API + PRODUCT_CAPPING_ENDPOINT, serviceHandler::getStockCapForProducts)
            .PUT(yamlConfig.getEnvPrefix() + STOCK_CAP_API + ADD_PRODUCT_CAP_FOR_CUSTOMER, RequestPredicates.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML), serviceHandler::AddStockCap)
            .build();
    }
}
```

The handler mehtod for the PUT endpoint looks like this:

```java
@NonNull
public Mono<ServerResponse> AddStockCap(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    log.info("Adding new stock caps");
    serverRequest.bodyToMono(CustomerCap.class)
        .flatMap(stockCapService::addCustomerStockCap)
        .doOnEach(result -> System.out.println("Cap added - " + result));
    return ServerResponse.ok().build();
}
```

The `bodyToMono` is mapped to a class that represents the XML payload like the one below, and the attribute Customer inside the class is also mapped to a class in the same fashion.

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="customerCap")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CustomerCap {
    @XmlElement
    private List<Customer> customer;

    public List<Customer> getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(List<Customer> customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
}
```

The implementation for the addCustomerStockCap is

```java
@Override
public Mono<Boolean> addCustomerStockCap(CustomerCap customerCap) {
    log.info("Starting adding process");
    customerCap.getCustomer().forEach(customer -> {
        final var customerUID = customer.getCustomerNumber();
        customer.getCap().forEach(cap -> {
            redisCommands.hset(String.join(SEP, STOCK_CAP, customerUID, cap.getMaterialNumber()), CAP_LIMIT, String.valueOf(cap.getCustomerCapLimit()));
            redisCommands.hset(String.join(SEP, STOCK_CAP, customerUID, cap.getMaterialNumber()), VALID_FROM, String.valueOf(cap.getCapValidFrom()));
            redisCommands.hset(String.join(SEP, STOCK_CAP, customerUID, cap.getMaterialNumber()), VALID_TO, String.valueOf(cap.getCapValidTo()));
            setExpirationOnHash(customerUID, cap);
        });
    });
    return Mono.just(Boolean.TRUE);
}
```

The method to handle the endpoint is being invoked properly and I can see the "Addin new stock caps" message on the log, but then the `addCustomerStockCap` is never invoked, with no exceptions or errors are being thrown, the method simply doesn't execute.

Another test that I did was creating a controller instead of a functional endpoint. The controller method ended up like this

```java
@PutMapping(STOCK_CAP_API + ADD_PRODUCT_CAP_FOR_CUSTOMER)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void AddStockCap(@RequestBody CustomerCap customerCap) {
    log.info("Adding new stock caps");;
    stockCapService.addCustomerStockCap(customerCap);
}
```

When I did this I got some errors on the XML parse that I fixed only adding the annotation `@NoArgsConstructor` to the `CustomerCap` and other element classes. After this fix, the controller/endpoint worked as expected.

The problem still is that I need to make it work on the functional endpoint, we have several applications and we use functional endpoints as our standard so leaving only this endpoint like this wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `Mono` is never subscribed and thus nothing is emitted and as a consequence `stockCapService::addCustomerStockCap` is never invoked. The following should work:

```java
@NonNull
public Mono<ServerResponse> AddStockCap(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    log.info("Adding new stock caps");
    serverRequest.bodyToMono(CustomerCap.class)
        .flatMap(stockCapService::addCustomerStockCap)
        .doOnEach(result -> System.out.println("Cap added - " + result))
        .subscribe();
    return ServerResponse.ok().build();
}
```

Or

```java
@NonNull
public Mono<ServerResponse> AddStockCap(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    log.info("Adding new stock caps");
    return serverRequest.bodyToMono(CustomerCap.class)
        .flatMap(stockCapService::addCustomerStockCap)
        .doOnEach(result -> System.out.println("Cap added - " + result))
        .flatMap(ServerResponse.ok().build());
}
```

---

Update 21/11/2021

Try the following. You don't really need `addCustomerStockCap` to return a `Mono<Boolean>`:

```java
@Override
public Boolean addCustomerStockCap(CustomerCap customerCap) {
    log.info("Starting adding process");
    customerCap.getCustomer().forEach(customer -> {
        final var customerUID = customer.getCustomerNumber();
        customer.getCap().forEach(cap -> {
            redisCommands.hset(String.join(SEP, STOCK_CAP, customerUID, cap.getMaterialNumber()), CAP_LIMIT, String.valueOf(cap.getCustomerCapLimit()));
            redisCommands.hset(String.join(SEP, STOCK_CAP, customerUID, cap.getMaterialNumber()), VALID_FROM, String.valueOf(cap.getCapValidFrom()));
            redisCommands.hset(String.join(SEP, STOCK_CAP, customerUID, cap.getMaterialNumber()), VALID_TO, String.valueOf(cap.getCapValidTo()));
            setExpirationOnHash(customerUID, cap);
        });
    });
    return Boolean.TRUE;
}
```

And now you can somewhat simplify your `AddStockCap` (`flatMap` turns a `map`):

```java
@NonNull
public Mono<ServerResponse> AddStockCap(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    log.info("Adding new stock caps");
    return serverRequest.bodyToMono(CustomerCap.class)
        .map(stockCapService::addCustomerStockCap)
        .flatMap(ServerResponse.ok().build());
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work too. Actually, I tried several different ways, when I try this one I get an error 415, the application cannot accept an XML, to fix it I add the @XMLElement and other relevant annotation to the CustomerCap.class which fixes the error, but still, the addcustomerStockCap is not executed. My feeling is there is something wrong with this mapping of the body to the CustomerCap

Comment: Does `addcustomerStockCap` return anything? Can you add its implementation to the question? Thanks!

Comment: I added the implementation, for now, I made it only return a Boolean, thank you.

Comment: Since it is working on a "regular" Controller it should work as I suggested. Have you tried both options?

Comment: Yes, but same result, nothing happens

Comment: I've added another option, please check it. Thanks! If this does not work then there must be something wrong with your functional endpoints.

Comment: It didn't work but I managed to find a workaround, it's not a good solution, but at least my method is getting invoked now. I changed the implementation to return a Boolean as you suggested and instead of only returning ok().build() I added the return of my method on the body of the response,  like this:

`@NonNull
 public Mono<ServerResponse> AddStockCap(ServerRequest serverRequest)
 {
  log.info("Adding new stock caps");
  return ServerResponse.ok().body(serverRequest.bodyToFlux(CustomerCap.class).map(stockCapService::addCustomerStockCap), Boolean.class);
 }`

Not ideal but it works

Comment: Then post it as an answer and accept it so that the question can be closed. Additionally, if I help you in any way consider upvoting my answer ;) Thanks!

Comment: It helped a lot, thank you for all the ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that worked for me to make sure the method is invoked was to add its result as the response body.

The problematic method ended up like this:

```java
@Override
public Boolean addCustomerStockCap(CustomerCap customerCap) {
  log.info("Starting adding process");
  customerCap.getCustomer().forEach(customer -> {
      final var customerUID = customer.getCustomerNumber();
      customer.getCap().forEach(cap -> {
          redisCommands.hset(String.join(SEP, STOCK_CAP, customerUID, cap.getMaterialNumber()), CAP_LIMIT, String.valueOf(cap.getCustomerCapLimit()));
          redisCommands.hset(String.join(SEP, STOCK_CAP, customerUID, cap.getMaterialNumber()), VALID_FROM, String.valueOf(cap.getCapValidFrom()));
          redisCommands.hset(String.join(SEP, STOCK_CAP, customerUID, cap.getMaterialNumber()), VALID_TO, String.valueOf(cap.getCapValidTo()));
          setExpirationOnHash(customerUID, cap);
      });
  });
  return Boolean.TRUE;
}
```

And the handler like this

```java
@NonNull
public Mono<ServerResponse> AddStockCap(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    log.info("Adding new stock caps");
    return ServerResponse.ok().body(serverRequest.bodyToFlux(CustomerCap.class).map(stockCapService::addCustomerStockCap), Boolean.class);
}
```

Not ideal as the goal was for this endpoint to only return a 200 code with no body, but it's a workaround until a found another way to invoke it.

Also on spring documentation, for XML and JSON payload we should use Flux instead of Mono

> The following example extracts the body to a Flux (or a Flow in Kotlin), where Person objects are decoded from someserialized form, such as JSON or XML:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn-handler-functions